# How to store the empty value in arraylist in android?

Tags: android

In my project I created an **arraylist to store selected checkboxes values**. i.e If a checkbox is selected I am storing the id value of it in the arraylist and if it is unselected I am deleting that from the arraylist. **Also if no checkbox is selected or unselected in that page I am storing "00" in the arraylist.** The **if and elseif conditions are working fine** in my code but the **else part is not working..**Where I went wrong? Please help me regarding this....

My Code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> selchkboxlist = new ArrayList<String>();

cbs[k].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            selchkboxlist.add(Integer.toString(v.getId()));
            System.out.println("chkboxlist size" + selchkboxlist.size());
            System.out.println("selected checkboxes" + selchkboxlist);
        } 
        else if(!(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()))
        {
            selchkboxlist.remove(Integer.toString(v
                    .getId()));
            System.out.println("after delete chkboxlist size" + selchkboxlist.size());
            System.out.println("un selected checkboxes" + selchkboxlist);
        }
        else
        {
            selchkboxlist.add("00");
            System.out.println("nothing selected selected checkboxes"
                    + selchkboxlist);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: the else part isn't reachable ... the box is either checked or not, there is no "else"

Comment: then if nothing is selected then how can I save a value by default?

Answer (score 1):

The else case will never be entered since a checkbox is either checked, or not checked.

The onclick listener is not called until you actually click on the checkbox.

I am not entirely sure what you want to accomplish, but you might want to add only checked checkboxes to a list of checked items.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes can only be checked or not checked, the else statment is unreachable in your code sample.

Use the OnCheckedChangeListener instead of on click:

```
selchkboxlist.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            //user checked checkbox
        }else{
            //user unchecked checkbox
        }
    }
});
```

Then when "submitting" your checkbox do this check in your loop to see if user has not selected the box

if(!checkbox.isChecked())
selchkboxlist.add("00");